# Nessus does not send e-mail after setting up smtp server

Tags: smtp, nessus

I have entered the following settings in the Nessus SMTP area:

```
Host: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 587
Encryption: Force TLS
Auth Method: Login
username: someuser@gmail.com
password: mypass
```

I get the following error once I try send a test e-mail:

> Error (500): It was not possible to email this scan: SMTP
>   Authentication      method 'LOGIN' failed: 534-5.7.14
>    Please log in via your web
>   browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again.
>
> 534-5.7.14 Learn more at  534 5.7.14
>   https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 p187sm2864006pfb.3 -
>   gsmtp

Answer (score 2):

Change Auth Method to PLAIN.

Make these setting changes in your gmail account -

1. Login to Gmail account, open settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP -> IMAP Access. Enable IMAP.
2. Go to - "https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps" while you are logged in to gmail and from same browser. Click on "Turn On".

After these settings are done, send a test email from Nessus Web UI.
You should get a notification noting email sent successfully.

Answer (score 0):

@Prateek's answer is correct and should be marked as answer.

However, I would also like to add that if using 2FA on your gmail account, you will need to create an application-specific password in this case as indicated in the link Prateek provided.